# Sharepoint 2013 - Workflow Email Reminder

Tags: 2013, workflow, email, reminder

I am using SP 2013, and hoping to create a workflow.

I added a list that needs a workflow on it. The issue I am running into is that this is a list that gets updated at random, but the entire list needs an annual review.

I am hoping to set up a workflow to send out an annual email reminder on the list as a whole (not individual items, and not when a change is made to the list.)

Is there a way to do this?

*I cannot set a "364 days after created by date" alert, as the items on this list are entered sporadically.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to create a site workflow. It will not be dependable on list items. Then you run it on schedule once a year.  http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-2013-create-start-site-workflow.htm